# Allocating space to mounts

Tags: linux, hadoop

My real objective is to clean existing nodes from a Hadoop cluster, claim the space etc. and do a fresh installation of another distro.

Below is the space descr. of one of the **master**(namenode):

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-root
                      2.0G  739M  1.2G  39% /
tmpfs                  24G     0   24G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  194M   65M  120M  36% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-home
                      248M   12M  224M   5% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-nsr  248M   11M  226M   5% /nsr
/dev/mapper/vg00-opt  3.1G   79M  2.8G   3% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-itm  434M   11M  402M   3% /opt/IBM/ITM
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp  2.0G   68M  1.9G   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  2.0G  1.6G  305M  85% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr_local
                      248M   11M  226M   5% /usr/local
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  2.0G  820M  1.1G  43% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-FSImage
                      917G  3.3G  867G   1% /opt/hadoop-FSImage
/dev/mapper/vg00-Zookeeper
                      917G  200M  870G   1% /opt/hadoop-Zookeeper
```

And one of the **slave**(datanodes)(the others too have 4-8 local disks and some mounted NFS drives):

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-root
                      2.0G  411M  1.5G  22% /
tmpfs                  36G     0   36G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/mpathap1  194M   67M  118M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-home
                      248M   11M  226M   5% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-nsr  248M   11M  226M   5% /nsr
/dev/mapper/vg00-opt  3.1G   82M  2.8G   3% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-itm  434M   11M  402M   3% /opt/IBM/ITM
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp  2.0G   68M  1.9G   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  2.0G  1.2G  690M  64% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr_local
                      248M   11M  226M   5% /usr/local
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  2.0G  1.5G  392M  80% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-00   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-00
/dev/mapper/vg00-01   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-01
/dev/mapper/vg00-02   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-02
/dev/mapper/vg00-03   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-03
/dev/mapper/vg00-04   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-04
/dev/mapper/vg00-05   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-05
/dev/mapper/vg00-06   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-06
/dev/mapper/vg00-07   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-07
```

During the new installation, I have run into space issues for all the nodes/hosts

```
Not enough disk space on host (l1032lab.se.com). A minimum of 1GB is required for "/usr" mount. A minimum of 2GB is required for "/" mount.
Not enough disk space on host (l1033lab.se.com). A minimum of 1GB is required for "/usr" mount. A minimum of 2GB is required for "/" mount.
Not enough disk space on host (l1034lab.se.com). A minimum of 1GB is required for "/usr" mount. A minimum of 2GB is required for "/" mount.
Not enough disk space on host (l1035lab.se.com). A minimum of 1GB is required for "/usr" mount. A minimum of 2GB is required for "/" mount.
```

Now the installation requires a lot of space under /, /usr, /var and /home mounts which on both master and the slaves is less but there is lots of space in master under these two disks:

```
/dev/mapper/vg00-FSImage
                      917G  200M  870G   1% /opt/hadoop-FSImage
/dev/mapper/vg00-Zookeeper
                      917G  6.5G  864G   1% /opt/hadoop-Zookeeper
```

and on slaves under these 8 disks.

```
/dev/mapper/vg00-00   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-00
/dev/mapper/vg00-01   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-01
/dev/mapper/vg00-02   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-02
/dev/mapper/vg00-03   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-03
/dev/mapper/vg00-04   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-04
/dev/mapper/vg00-05   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-05
/dev/mapper/vg00-06   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-06
/dev/mapper/vg00-07   559G   33M  559G   1% /opt/hadoop-07
```

I'm a bit confused as how to proceed - I was wondering if I can partition one or more of these disks and allocate those under /, /usr etc. and proceed with the installation but then will these disk partitioning and mounting/un-mounting corrupt the existing /, /usr etc. mounts ?

Comment: I am struggling with similar issue, did you find some insights for your question ?

Comment: Yeah underwent a complex(for me :P ) to get the space allocated ! What is your exact issue? I suggest you post it as an independent question may be I can provide some useful inputs

Comment: Hi, I created this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123630/hadoop-create-mysterious-file-and-full-disk