# hadoop create mysterious file and full disk

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and struggle a lot with full disk issues.
Now I have been running a local pig script, and my disk has been filled up.
there are some files I have no clue what are they about, but they seems to be problematic to my disk usage. Namely:

```
/dev/mapper/sda2_crypt -> ../dm-0
/dev/mapper/vg00-home -> ../dm-5
/dev/mapper/vg00-root -> ../dm-1
/dev/mapper/vg00-swap -> ../dm-4
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr -> ../dm-2
/dev/mapper/vg00-var -> ../dm-3
```

These files are binary file. 
I should remove them but don't have the rights to do so.
I have been looking around to understand where do they come from, without finding any information. And I would like to configurate the partition on which they are written, but can't really find where should I configure it (is it in hadoop or in pig ? which variable ?).
Any help appreciated ;)

Comment: From what I understood, the system is using LVM or some other volume manager. As u said, there are space issues so first you need to find the volumes that are running low on space and add memory to those using lvextend(LVM command) or something similar